# Ubuntu doesn't boot (grub rescue - Unknown filesystem)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 15.04

I turned up my PC like every day, but today doesn't boot normally.

After the BIOS POST and the "Loading operative system...", it shows something like this:

```
Error: Unknown filesystem
grub rescue>
```

And after I found a solution (with my phone) like this:

```
set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub/
insmod normal
```

Doesn't work because fail again (I tried with different numbers instead of 6 ). 
Then I loaded my Live-CD of Ubuntu 15.04 and when I go to "Disks", it says:

[image]

```
Part. 1 - 996 GB - Unknown
Part. 2 - 4,2 GB - Extended partition
Part. 5 - 4,2 GB - Swap partition
```

(All is Ubuntu 15.04, doesn't exist a Windows partition)
And:

```
11 bad sectors
```

I think the part. 1 was lost, but are there a way to recover it?
And the "11 bad sectors" warning means my HDD is dying?